# SQL Server stored procedure performance impact

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to write stored procedure that can be used for multipurpose. Can anyone help me find the best practice to write a stored procedure in SQL Server from these approaches? And what are the performance impacts of each of them?

Approach 1 : 
parameters @KEY, @VALUE

```
IF @KEY = 'ISACTIVE'
BEGIN 
    SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE 
    FROM STATE 
    WHERE ISACTIVE = @VALUE
END
ELSE IF @KEY = 'STATECODE'
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE 
    FROM STATE  
    WHERE STATECODE = @VALUE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE 
    FROM STATE
END
```

Approach : 2 
parameters @ISACTIVE, @STATECODE

```
SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE 
FROM STATE
WHERE ISACTIVE = ISNULL(@ISACTIVE, ISACTIVE) 
  AND STATECODE = ISNULL(@STATECODE,STATECODE)
```

Approach : 3

parameters @KEY, @VALUE

```
DECLARE @SQLQRY NVARCHAR(500)
SET @SQLQRY = 'SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE FROM STATE WHERE ' + @KEY +' = ' + @VALUE
EXEC @SQLQRY
```

Which one is the best approach in terms of performance as well as re-usability?

Or is there any other option to achieve this?

Comment: you should benchmark....but if that's your bottleneck you have bigger problems....

Comment: What is the size of this table ? This is from memory, but I think If the table size is less than 64 KB, indexing would not have any impact as that is the minimum set of data read by SQL Server . That said, approach 3 is definitely not recommended as it would be prone to sql injection.

Comment: As far as re-usability concern 3rd Approach is 'Ok' but as far as performance concern I would suggest Approach 1 because SP are compiled one, so that SQL Server can decide execution plan at the compile time depending upon your conditions. There are chances of runtime errors in 3rd Approach also in 3rd approach execution plan will get decided at runtime because of dynamic query. In Approach 2 NULL check may take time for values if no. of rows in table and checking conditions are more. Only disadvantage of Approach 1 is if no of conditions get increases you will need to write code more.

Comment: As far as re-usability concern 3rd Opt is 'Ok' but There are chances of runtime errors also in 3rd Opt execution plan will get decided at runtime because of dynamic query. So as far as performance concern I would suggest Opt 1, because SPs are pre-compiled, so that SQL Server can decide execution plan at compile time depending upon your conditions. In Opt 2 NULL check may take time if no. of rows in table and checking conditions are more. Opt 1 is good, Only disadvantage is, if no of conditions get increases you will need to write code more. But for performance, accuracy of result, is best.

Comment: Personally - having done a lot like this in the past - I'd opt for 2-3 specialized queries even though they (are/appear) similar right now. Easier to read - easier to expand - easier to debug - easier to optimize.

Comment: The issue with option 1 is the data type of parameter `@VALUE` will differ depending on the specified key. It is always best to match parameter types with the referenced columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with the **Approach 2**, which is both maintainable as well as permanent in my opinion.

In the *Approach 1*, you are duplicating the code hence maintenance wise it's not the best approach.

In the *Approach 3*, where you are using a dynamic sql query, it's not the best way to do things as it does not provide intellisense support as well as it limits the SQL server's ability to optimize the performance.

If you face any performance issues, consider introducing an index on the columns "ISACTIVE" and "STATECODE". Also analyse the query execution plan and use the profiler to do further investigations if required.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write stored procedure that can be used for multipurpose.

Taking into account this desire (although I have my concerns about this need), ***it depends***.

- **Approach 1:** You will start repeating a lot of code as your business rules get complex. When you realise, you have multiple repeated selects with possibly several joins or `EXISTS` clauses and maybe another programmer that has to modify something forgets to edit one of the queries. Things get even more complicated when you start to apply multiple filters at the same time (like `SELECT` where `IsActive = 0 AND StateCode = 'AR'`). This approach makes it easier to return different result sets depending of the key you want to filter.
- **Aproach 2:** You can stack filters together and you will just have to write your `SELECT` once, but you will kill performance specially if you have many rows and the filters apply on different tables. Another problem is that you might have to supply a replacement value for both ends of the comparison: if we want to select just the records that have `NULL` on `StateCode` then you will have to do a filter like `ISNULL(StateCode, 'SomeImpossibleStateCode') = ISNULL(@StateCode, 'SomeImpossibleStateCode')` or like `(@StateCode IS NULL AND StateCode IS NULL) OR (@StateCode = StateCode)`.
- **Approach 3:** As it's dynamic, it's harder to maintain, dependent tables/columns won't show up on views like `sysdepends` or the such and you might have to take additional measures to prevent SQL Injection. However, it gives the flexibility to avoid conditional filters altogether, which will make your query simpler and more performant. You can even recieve a table as input parameter which includes the filters you want to apply, the logical operator (`AND` or `OR`) that links them and the filter precedences.

**Conclusion:**

- If your table isn't big and the amount of keys you might search is low, **approach 2** would be the best, although you will have to test performance.
- **Approach 3** seems the best to handle all scenarios, including performance.
- I'd definitely avoid **approach 1** as it's very prone to maintainance errors. If you ever feel that different keys need to return different columns or apply different query conditions, then it's time to split your do-it-all SP into different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Must read: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog. As is approach 2 is bad, but can become the best.

Here is a short summary of the linked article.

**Approach 1** is good from the performance point of view. Optimiser can generate good plans and use indexes if they are available.
The problem here is the number of possible variants/permutations of the query. If you have three parameters Key1, Key2, Key3 it would become a rather ugly nested IF three level deep. If you add few more parameters, it becomes unpractical from the maintenance point of view.

**Approach 2** is good from the maintenance point of view, but given "as is" it is bad from the performance point of view. `ISACTIVE = ISNULL(@ISACTIVE, ISACTIVE)` will be evaluated even when `@ISACTIVE` is NULL and may prevent efficient use of indexes.

The query should be rewritten like this:

```
SELECT ID, STATECODE, STATENAME, ISACTIVE 
FROM STATE
WHERE
    (ISACTIVE = @ISACTIVE OR @ISACTIVE IS NULL) 
    AND (STATECODE = @STATECODE OR @STATECODE IS NULL)
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is very important. Essentially, it allows optimiser to inline the actual values of parameters into the query, simplify logical expressions and generate the plan, which is as good as in Approach 1 or better. See the article for details.

**Approach 3** would produce good plans, as in Approach 1, though not the best as in Approach 2. Maintenance is not bad, though dynamic SQL has its difficulties. If you go this route you should read another article by Erland [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).